# How do I make a new SSD my boot drive and keep my HDD as the storage drive?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I just got a new SSD card, plugged it in, and everything is detecting it. However, all of the tutorials I've found online only work for Windows. How can I make the new SSD my boot drive while still keeping my old HDD as a storage drive? Should I just reinstall Ubuntu and load my backup?

Comment: you can reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 in the new SSD and then format (either during the install process or after that) the Hard Drive as ext4 for files and mount it at the startup

Comment: If I do that, will I be able to use a backup from Deja Dup to restore my data?

Comment: Try creating a new partition table in the new SSD in the GPT type. Keep the drive unformatted. Then the Ubuntu installer **should** find the unformatted space and offer to install Ubuntu alongside the installed version

Comment: what exactly do you want to backup ? where is the backup stored ?

Comment: I used the Deja Dup backup system to backup all the files on my computer. If I reinstall Ubuntu, I should be able to restore my backup, right? (I backed it up on Google Drive)

Comment: I think yes you can, but in my opinion I dont think that is the best way to go..

Comment: I couldn't use the Ubuntu installer to activate the SSD.

Comment: Use GParted on a Live USB to copy paste the Ubuntu partitions you wish to keep from the HDD to the SSD and then install GRUB on the SSD. Or clone Ubuntu from the HDD using dd, Gnome-Disks, Clonezilla etc. I uess Deja Dup might be an "etc", but sounds a little more complex than the rest.

Comment: Many SSD need firmware update. If HDD is gpt, better to do new install as gpt has partition table at both start & end of drive and any image copy then does not work unless drive is exactly same size. You can create /home on HDD or use it as data partition(s). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk